# Unity3D always switches back to C# 4.0?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

**I have already done this:**

- **Unity3D > Edit > Project Settings > Player**

  - **Scripting Runtime Version:** Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)
  - **Api Compability Level:** .NET 4.6
- **Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Tools for Unity**

  - **Access to project properties:** true
- **Visual Studio > Project > Properties**

  - **Application > Target Framework:** .NET Framework 4.6.2
  - **Build > Advanced > Language Version:** C# 6.0
  - **then save**

**After this:** every error disappears that were there due to using new stuff.

**But:**

- As soon as Unity3D does something referencing something in VS, the **Project Settings** go back to the old one.

  - For example:

    - I delete a `.cs` file in Unity3D, then I switch back to VS. It says that the Project was changed outside, so I have to reload it. After reloading, the settings are reverted.
    - I double click on a `.cs` file in Unity3D because I would like to open it in VS. Unity3D switches to VS for me and after that the project settings are reverted.
  - Etc.

**The code compiles in Unity3D**, everything is fine but everytime I use something new **one new error will pop up in the error list** which is a **bit distracting.**

**Question:**

- How can I disable this reverting?
- Or how can I supress these errors?

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I use 2017.3.1f1